# Using grep to find specific line - pass that line to sed - edit character at position x

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

I need to find all lines that begin with 1 and replace position 14.
I need to find all lines that begin with 5 and replace at position 41. - et.c.

I want to replace all occurences of a string:

```
sed 's/string/replace/g' -
```

the string can change, and I really only want to replace the first position - this position is always the same and occurs at position 14, therefore:

```
sed 's/string/replace/14'
```

Different lines do not need this character replaced.  I only want to replace the character position if its line begins with a certain code.

This string occurs at place 14 on a line that begins with 1
This string occurs at place 41 on a line that begins with 5
This string occurs at place 45 on a line that begins with 8

Find the string

```
grep -E '^1' $DEST/$FILE_NAME$DATE.txt
```

Therefore:

```
grep -E '^1' $DEST/$FILE_NAME$DATE.txt | sed 's/./'$CODE'/14'
grep -E '^5' $DEST/$FILE_NAME$DATE.txt | sed 's/./'$CODE'/41'
grep -E '^8' $DEST/$FILE_NAME$DATE.txt | sed  's/./'$CODE'/45'
```

The above doesn't actually write to the file though, but seems to do what I want.

```
grep -E '^8' $DEST/$FILE_NAME$DATE.txt | sed  -i 's/./'$CODE'/45' $DEST/$FILE_NAME$DATE.txt
```

The above writes to the file, but ignores the grepped line, and replaces the character in position 45 for each line.

Also, multiple similar files may be concatenated - therefore I need to find all lines that begin with 1 and replace position 14.
I need to find all lines that begin with 5 and replace at position 41. - et.c.

Sorry ahead of time if this is easily answered by another post - probably using awk and regex. I haven't found this particular case though.

Comment: why grep, then sed output of grep, when sed can select files like grep too?

Comment: I've come across this - not sure if I understood it in a way to do this.  Can you give me an example?

Comment: sed -n "s/pattern1/pattern2/p" is the general syntax for selecting only lines containing pattern1, and replace pattern1 against pattern2. that is, sort of doing grep, then work on matching pattern lines.

Comment: Because I need to replace based on a different pattern that I'm searching for. tkocmathla just got it

Comment: you can string sed expressions together, separated by ";".   sed -n "/pattern/p" selects only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` can make changes to lines that match a regex, so `grep` isn't necessary. The matching expression comes first, then the substitution expression:

```
sed -i "/^1/ s/./$CODE/14" $DEST/$FILE_NAME$DATE.txt 
sed -i "/^5/ s/./$CODE/41" $DEST/$FILE_NAME$DATE.txt 
sed -i "/^8/ s/./$CODE/45" $DEST/$FILE_NAME$DATE.txt
```

[Selecting lines with `sed` (Addresses)](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html#Addresses)